# Cordova is not recognized... immediately after installation

Tags: node.js, cordova, cmd, cordova-3

I'm stuck with this very frustrating problem while trying to install Apache Cordova. I issue `npm install -g cordova` in my `cmd` (Windows 8.1, 64 bits), and everything seems to be fine. But even after the installation when trying to type `cordova` it is not recognized as a command by the `cmd`. This is my first question on StackOverflow, so I may have missed something crucial or made a noob mistake. I hope someone out there can help me! :)

Cheers,

`cmd` session:

```
C:\Users\James>npm install -g cordova
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
```

... bunch of text here ...

```
C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova -> C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\npm
\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova
cordova@3.3.1-0.1.2 C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova
├── ncallbacks@1.0.0
├── open@0.0.3
├── semver@1.1.0
├── colors@0.6.2
├── mime@1.2.11
├── q@0.9.7
├── follow-redirects@0.0.3 (underscore@1.5.2)
├── optimist@0.6.0 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.5)
├── shelljs@0.1.2
├── glob@3.2.7 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.2.14)
├── lodash@2.4.1
├── elementtree@0.1.5 (sax@0.3.5)
├── tar@0.1.19 (inherits@2.0.1, block-stream@0.0.7, fstream@0.1.25)
├── xcode@0.6.2 (node-uuid@1.3.3, pegjs@0.6.2)
├── prompt@0.2.7 (revalidator@0.1.6, pkginfo@0.3.0, read@1.0.5, utile@0.1.7, win
ston@0.6.2)
├── request@2.22.0 (json-stringify-safe@4.0.0, aws-sign@0.3.0, forever-agent@0.5
.0, qs@0.6.6, tunnel-agent@0.3.0, oauth-sign@0.3.0, cookie-jar@0.3.0, node-uuid@
1.4.1, http-signature@0.10.0, hawk@0.13.1, form-data@0.0.8)
├── express@3.0.0 (methods@0.0.1, fresh@0.1.0, range-parser@0.0.4, debug@0.7.4,
cookie@0.0.4, crc@0.2.0, commander@0.6.1, mkdirp@0.3.3, send@0.1.0, connect@2.6.
0)
├── plist@0.4.3 (xmlbuilder@0.4.3, xmldom@0.1.17)
├── ripple-emulator@0.9.18 (connect-xcors@0.5.2, colors@0.6.0-1, accounting@0.3.
2, request@2.12.0, moment@1.7.2, express@3.1.0)
├── npm@1.3.22
├── plugman@0.17.0 (ncallbacks@1.1.0, osenv@0.0.3, bplist-parser@0.0.4, undersco
re@1.4.4, semver@2.0.11, nopt@1.0.10, dep-graph@1.1.0, rc@0.3.0, tar.gz@0.1.1, x
code@0.6.3, npm@1.3.4)
└── jshint@1.1.0 (peakle@0.0.1, cli@0.4.5, underscore@1.4.4, esprima@1.1.0-dev,
minimatch@0.2.14)

C:\Users\James>cordova
'cordova' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\James>cordova
'cordova' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\James>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's likely that `C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\npm\` isn't in your path so even though cordova is installed globally (as npm defines it) it isn't working as expected.

Use the `SET` command to check the value for your `NODE_PATH` or `PATH`.  If the npm directory tree isn't listed...that's a problem, but easily fixed.

If you don't want npm to save to this directory, check the [npm configuration options](https://npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-config.html) and the [npm folders docs](https://npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html) to see what you can change in this regard...

Answer (score 5):

I just had this issue after a "successful" install, and found the cordova files under a folder called node modules in my users folder. I added `c:\users\dewd\node_modules\cordova\bin` to my path, restarted a cmd prompt and then cordova ran ok.

They don't like to make it easy do they!!

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your PATH

```
C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin
```

By default the folder

```
C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData
```

is not visible. configure your explorer to see it or navigate through the CLI

Answer (score 2):

if there still is not working check the PATH.

make sure the order is **node; npm; cordova**

example of the PATH

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
%ANT_HOME%\bin;
%NODEJS%;
%NPM%;
C:\Program Files (x86)\WinAnt\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;
%CORDOVA%
```

To be very clean, create a new system variables NODEJS NPM CORDOVA

`NODEJS="C:\Program Files\Nodejs"`

`NPM'="%appdata%\npm\;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm;"`

`CORDOVA="%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin"`

Then edit the PATH in system variables and add `%NODEJS%` in front of anything that uses nodejs after add `%NPM%` and `%CORDOVA%` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

this has been answered several times here...I will post my answer nonetheless.

In your prompt/terminal type this:`npm config set prefix` . Hope it helps ☺☺☺